# Calling a JPanel onto a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm having troubles calling a JPanel I made into a JFrame.

The JPanel is called "SubnetPanel" ==>

```
SubnetPanel panel = new SubnetPanel(String a, String b, String c);
```

In my JFrame, I made a button.

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Geef de naam in : ", 
    "Naam", 1);
    String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Geef het netwerkadres in : ", 
    "Netwerkadres", 1);
    String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Geef het subnetmask in : ", 
    "Subnetmask", 1);

    this.add(new SubnetPanel(a,b,c) {
             @Override
             public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

                Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 40, 40);
                g2.setColor(Color.blue);
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                g2.draw(line);
             }
        });
        this.setVisible( true );

}
```

But when I execute my JFrame and click the button, the JFrame does not appear.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you see? Just the panel? Or just the frame? Or the panel and the frame?

Comment: Now I'm having nothing but a JPanel I coded and an empty JFrame, with just a JButton and `private void JButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic code for adding (or removing) a component from a visible frame is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

In your case the "panel" would be the content pane of your JFrame.

Also, when you do custom painting, you also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel, so the layout manager can use this information to set the size/location of the panel.

Comment: so in my case it would be: `panel.add(SubnetPanel);` ?

Comment: Does the "panel" variable reference the "content pane" of your frame?

Comment: When you add components to a frame, the components are added to the "content pane" (which is just a JPanel) of the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to understand the structure of a JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've added the panel to the frame, it will initially be located at (0,0) with a size of 0×0, so you won't be able to see it. You'll need to size and position it, such as by calling `pack()` on the frame.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to add the `ActionListner` on the `JButton`.

Try in this way

```
    JButton jButton = new JButton("Click"); // Your actual button is here
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
            jButtonActionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm using netbeans, so I think I don't need this?

Comment: What netbeans does in the background? check the code and find `addActionListener()` method.